# Development resources for IBM WCM/WebSphere

Tags: websphere, wcm

I recently started a new position at a company that uses IBM's WebSphere Portal, and it is completely new to me. I was wondering if there was a good resource anyone knew for development techniques using said platform.

Basically what I've been asked to do is create a dynamic newsletter page to speed up the publishing time for a new set of newsletters/articles. I have no idea how to generate dynamic content with WebSphere so that when a new article is published, it updates a landing page with a link to the new article.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of information on the various IBM sites (disclaimer I work for IBM, but not with Portal). This [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0703_smit/0703_smit.html) seems to be relevant.